# NPE in FileChooser

Tags: java, windows, javafx-2

I'm trying to run some javafx application under windows 7. It works fine under archlinux.

I'm open the file chooser dialog in a following way:

```
  @Override
  public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(myInitialDir);
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Wav files (*.wav)", "*.wav");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
  }
```

How I mentioned above - everything is fine under linux, but under windows I get strange NPE:

```
Error:80070057 in SHCreateItemFromParsingName((PCWSTR)folder, NULL, IID_IShellItem, (void **)&pItem)
COM Error:80070057 0@0.
Error:80004005 in pOpenDialog->GetResults(&pFiles)
COM Error:80004005 5>?>7=0==0O >H81:0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.glass.ui.CommonDialogs.showFileChooser(CommonDialogs.java:120)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.showFileChooser(QuantumToolkit.java:1486)
    at javafx.stage.FileChooser.showDialog(FileChooser.java:285)
    at javafx.stage.FileChooser.showOpenDialog(FileChooser.java:234)
    at ru.gkalabin.diploma.gui.equalizer.EqualizerDemo$1.handle(EqualizerDemo.java:107)
```

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know anything about JavaFX, but shouldn't you be using a `JFileChooser` instead of a `FileChooser`?

Comment: @tieTYT it's a swing's component and it's not so simple to use swing components in javafx application

Comment: Which JFX build is used?

Comment: myInitialDir - is correctly set to be windows specific?

Comment: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21999

Comment: @AlexanderKirov I have problems with javafx 2.2.21-b11

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin try to use getCanonicalPath() for initial folder.

Comment: @AlexanderKirov `getCanonicalPath()` for initial folder didn't worked for me. I've removed setting initial directory and it works now. Thank you for help.

Comment: @GrigoryKalabin well, what is that path? =)

Comment: @AlexanderKirov `./samples/`. Looks like the problem was in "."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is issue :

[RT-21999 Win: FileChooser does not accept valid initial directory](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-21999)

Issue affects version : 2.2; Fix Version/s : Lombard, so fix is available in JFX8 (in JDK8).

To fix the issue, call `<fileName>.getCanonicalPath()` for initial folder.

---

Comments from developer:

> This issue is Windows 7-specific. It's not reproducible on older versions of Windows.
>
> A workaround is to pass an absolute path as an initial directory for the file chooser (see File.getAbsolutePath()/getCanonicalPath()).

And comment from user :

> Jason Winnebeck added a comment - Mar, 18 2013 04:30 PM
>   I've encountered this as well, with the exact same COM errors printed to stderr, resuling in NullPointerException. I actually tried getAbsolutePath at first, but that doesn't work for all paths, for some you have to use getCanonicalPath, thankfully I found this ticket that gave me that workaround. So, I don't have much additional information to offer, except here is some groovy code that reproduces it:

```
public void openFile() throws IOException {
  FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser()
  chooser.title = "Select FXML"
  chooser.setInitialDirectory( new File( "." ) );
  chooser.extensionFilters.add( new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter( 
    "FXML or SVG Files",
    ["*.fxml", "*.svg"] 
  ))

  Window window = sceneProperty.get().window
  File selected = chooser.showOpenDialog( window )
}
```

The error occurs regardless of the other settings (extension filter, which Window is used or null). Using `new File( "." ).canonicalFile` fixes the problem, so based on the other report, it seems that having `.` and `..` in the path is the likely cause.